# How to configure Mail v8.2 to supply a different default reply-to address in emails being sent?

Tags: mail.app, email, macos

I'm using Mail v8.2 on Macintosh OS X Yosemite and would like to transition to a new email address.  Therefore, I'd like to keep using my old email address for the time being and I have configured my new address to forward all email to my old address.

Now, I just need to set up my reply-to in every email I send, to default to specifying my new email address, so that recipients will eventually start using my new email address over time and eventually I can pull the trigger and drop the old one and switch to the new one.

How can I configure Mail v8.2 to use a different default reply-to email address for each email I send?  I don't see anything in the Preferences, nor in the account settings.  I have a pacbell.net account for my old email address that is hosted by Yahoo.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60980/how-to-set-reply-to-address-in-apple-mail) question sounds like a very similar request, shows this [About.com](http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/etalwaysreplyto.htm) article.

From the above answer: If you want to apply the reply-to all the time there's a hack you can do this via Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders '{"Reply-To" = "reply-to@address"; }'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Mail, under the View menu, you can choose which fields to show or hide, including Reply To.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I want to configure the default reply-to address.

Answer (score 1):

Start new email.

On the left you see a pull down arrow. It will open the option of Reply to:

[image: reply to]

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I want to configure the default reply-to address.