# How to set the Reply-To in Apple Mail exactly?

Tags: mail.app, email

I am trying to figure out the possible files that may affect the headers of outgoing emails when using Apple Mail. In particular I want to modify the `Reply-To` part.

I know that there are numerous solutions on the web, but apparently each one of the solutions that I have found is still missing some information that would work in my case.

Straightforward (manual) and terminal-based (automated solution) is the [following](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/60981/26354). Basically the automated is the elegant solution which includes the command `defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders '{"Reply-To" = "reply-to@address"; }'` The above one is based on the solutions:

- manual: https://www.lifewire.com/change-reply-to-header-os-x-mail-1172887
- automated: https://www.lifewire.com/add-reply-to-header-os-x-mail-1172899

However, it turns out that in the past the above methods were not really working for me, so I had to follow a different route. (As background info: I was working at an organization where employees would get a strange username by default, something like, jsmit1234 for someone called John Smith, and then I wanted to have a more human-friendly email address in the reply-to part of the email, with something like: john_smith@...) Clearly I am writing this email because by now (4 years later) I can not remember how I did it back then.

Anyway, another idea is to do factory reset to the Mail app. According to the information found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5118986), under `~/Library/` one should be able to delete the following files/directories:

`(directory) Caches/com.apple.mail` --- I can `cd` and view all the files. I assume I can delete the files as well.

`(directory) Saved Application State/com.apple.mail.savedState` --- I can `cd` into it, but I can not do `ls`. Interestingly I can not do `ls`, not even after changing to superuser with `sudo su`. In fact, if I perform the `sudo su` while being on the above directory I get the error message: 
`shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted`

`(file) Application Support/AddressBook/MailRecents-v4.abcdmr` --- There is however lots of files in the directory AddressBook and there is two more files like the above one, ending in `-shm` and `-wal` (where the latter is an SQLite Write-Ahead Log file according to the command `file`).

`(directory) Containers/com.apple.mail` --- I can `cd` into it, but I can not even perform `ls`, not even as root.

`(directory) Mail` --- I can `cd into it, but I can not even perform`ls`, not even as root.

`(file) Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist` --- I can view the contents. Interestingly though, there is another file called `com.apple.mail-shared.plist` under the `Preferences` directory and I can *not* view that file with `less`, not even as root.

`(file) Preferences/com.apple.mail.searchhistory.plist` --- There is no such file in my system.

For the record I am running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 and the Mail app is version 12.4 (3445.104.11).

Now, I would really like to avoid doing a factory reset, because this way I would lose about 4 years of emails from my previous organization. So, the question to you is the following: What other files or commands can affect the `Reply-To` part of the emails? (When I made the change in the past it was another terminal command because the above one did not work as expected even back then.)

I would appreciate any help on resolving this issue and I want to thank you in advance for your time on thinking about this matter and suggesting solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Skwoo8RjHSw

I deleted com.apple.mail savedState, and moved com.apple.mail and com.apple.MailServiceAgent to the desktop, as the video suggested. After restarting, the Mail App stopped its autocopy that I had set up.

Comment: This is indeed a good fix while I am still using the same laptop! Thank you very much!  (I am now using Catalina btw - not Mojave anymore.)